# How to get right sum from inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables one is orders and second is order_product in which I have to find out orders count, product count, totalamount in corresponding to store using store id from which I have successfully find out the orders count and product count but my totalamount is not coming correct.

**orders**:

```
...........................
 order_id      or_total_amt
...........................
    1           10           
    2           10         
    3           10
```

**order_product**

```
.................................
 op_id  op_order_id  st_id
.................................
   1       1          1
   2       2          2
   3       3          1
   4       3          1
```

I want below output but my totalamount value is coming wrong it is coming 30,but the correct value is 20 which i have mentioned in the right output below.

**output which i want:**

```
.........................................
 st_id    orders   product   totalmount
.........................................
   1         2        3          20
   2         1        1          10
```

I have tried the below query which is giving 30 value of totalamount which is wrong.

```
SELECT `op_st_id`,count(distinct orders.`order_id`)as orders,count(order_product.op_pr_id) as product
,sum(orders.or_total_amt) as totalamount from orders 
inner JOIN order_product on orders.order_id=order_product.op_order_id
group by `op_st_id`
```

Comment: The sum looks correct to me, so I don't understand what the issue is.

Comment: it is coming 30 for st_id 1 which is a wrong value i need 20 refer order table for totalamount.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT
    `st_id`,
    count(DISTINCT orders.`order_id`) AS orders,
    count(order_product.op_id) AS product,
    count(DISTINCT orders.`order_id`)*(sum(orders.or_total_amt)/count(order_product.op_id)) AS totalamount
FROM
    orders
INNER JOIN order_product ON orders.order_id = order_product.op_order_id
GROUP BY
    `st_id`
```